# Running emacs in GNU Screen overrides .emacs settings for [home] key binding in FreeBSD 8.2

Tags: emacs, gnu-screen, freebsd

If I use the following .emacs file, I am able to go to the beginning/end of the current line using the home/end keys as I would expect.

```
(keyboard-translate ?\C-h ?\C-?)

(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/sam/programs/go/go/misc/emacs/" t)
(require 'go-mode-load)

(global-set-key [kp-home]  'beginning-of-line) ; [Home]
(global-set-key [home]     'beginning-of-line) ; [Home]

(global-set-key [kp-end]  'end-of-line) ; [End]
(global-set-key [end]     'end-of-line) ; [End]
```

However, if I open up a screen session it does not function like this (the [home] key still brings me to the beginning of the buffer for some reason).

Here is my .screenrc file if anyone can spot anything funky in there:

```
term xterm
defutf8 on
defflow off
startup_message off

# terminfo and termcap for nice 256 color terminal
# allow bold colors - necessary for some reason
attrcolor b ".I"

# tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'

#use bash as the default login shell
defshell -bash
```

EDIT: Apparently, using M-x describe-key (as nschum suggested) says that [begin] is getting triggered when I press the home key on my keyboard when running emacs inside screen. When I run emacs outside of screen describe-key refers to [home] as expected. It looks like the "defutf8 on" is the only keyboard-related entry in my .screenrc - is there anything else in there that might be causing issues?

Comment: What does M-x describe-key say?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program in `screen`, the `screen` program can (and will) do this:

- `screen` has its own terminal description.  It tries to map (convert) the underlying terminal's key sequences into that.
- The conversion is not complete.  As a workaround, `screen` looks for customized terminal descriptions starting with `screen.$TERM`.  ncurses provides some useful ones.
- `screen` filters out (ignores) some key sequences which do not fit into its notion of how input should be done.

Most likely, your problem is in the first case.  If you do

```
infocmp xterm screen
```

(presuming that you are using the most-often suggested value for `TERM`, whether or not you *are* using `xterm`), you may notice a few lines like this:

```
kend: '\E[4~', '\EOF'.
khome: '\E[1~', '\EOH'.
```

The last column is the sequence (`\E` is the *escape* character) which `screen` will send to your program when it receives the middle column from `xterm`, etc.

The problem with the `.screenrc` is that it [overrides the `$TERM` value](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#index-term-22) to `xterm`, confusing `screen`:

```
term xterm
```

You would suppose that the conversion would be complete, but testing shows that it is not.  This sort of problem is *why* ncurses provides customized entries.  For example, [this entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-xfree86) from ncurses database is the one which takes effect on my machine given that `.screenrc` setting (because "xterm" is aliased to "xterm-new"):

```
screen.xterm-xfree86|screen.xterm-new|screen customized for modern xterm,
        bce@, bw,
        invis@, kIC@, kNXT@, kPRV@, meml@, memu@,
        sgr=%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p5%t;2%;m,
        E3@, use=screen+italics, use=screen+fkeys, use=xterm-new,
```

you may notice the `use=screen+fkeys`.  That says in effect: go ahead and use the keys that `screen` will use, since it is the simplest workaround.  Now there is a subtle problem: [`screen+fkeys`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_fkeys) looks like this:

```
screen+fkeys|function-keys according to screen,
        kend=\E[4~, kf1=\EOP, kf2=\EOQ, kf3=\EOR, kf4=\EOS, kfnd@,
        khome=\E[1~, kslt@,
```

because (in testing screen), it sent those keys rather than what was in the outer `$TERM` terminal description.  The inner `$TERM` is set to `xterm`, but `screen` uses this intermediate entry when it conveys special keys such as home/end to your session.